# Using differentials to determine the maximum error

Tags: calculus, geometry

Imagine this triangle

[image: We are interested in]

and the distance between city A and C.

Unfortunately, the clouds block the measurements of our telemetric devices. However, we once measured the distance between city A
and B as $7$ km and the device we applied at that time
had a measurement error of $0.1$ km.

We now measure the distance between city B and C with a second
device bearing measurement error of $0.3$ km. We find that
distance to be $4$ km.

---

**Calculating the distance between A and C**

Using the pythagorean theorem I calculate

$$b=\sqrt{7^2-4^2}$$
$$b=\sqrt{33}$$

**What is the maximum error occuring with my approach?**

I know I'm supposed to use differentials to calculate the maxiumum error here. But I'm unable to come up with an equation at the moment. Help is very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$\frac{\Delta y}{y}=\frac{1}{2}.\frac{\Delta x_1}{x_2}+\frac{1}{2}.\frac{\Delta x_2}{x_2}$$

You already have calculated $y$. You have $x_1 =7$ with error of $\Delta x_1=0.1$ . Same with $x_2=4$ with error of $\Delta x_2=0.3$.(please assum units in $km$)

Simply calculate $\Delta y$

Comment: Little typo $x_2$ instead of $x_1$ in the third fraction

Comment: Thanks! This helps. One further question: How do I compare $\Delta y$ with the error that would have occurred during a measurement without clouds based on the second device?

Comment: @Phaneron If you find the answer helpful. you may accept it.